# Android emulator cant start react-native app because has not enough space

Tags: android, react-native

I have several android emulators available in Android Studio:

[image]

**Nexus 6P API 19** runs perfectly my react native app, but **Nexus 5X API26** always raises this error when `run-android`:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:installDebug'.
> com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: Unknown failure: Error: android.os.ParcelableException: java.io.IOException: Requested internal only, but not enough space
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried to play with AVD settings? I suppose adding more space in the Internal Storage or sdcard could help here.

[image: AVD settings]